# a reference for topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

i am looking for a good and easy book about topology that everyone can understand it.also it be interesting.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/7520/33989

Comment: Give us a real sense of your intended audience. 3-year-olds? 12-year-olds, college students? Is it just for you? "Everyone" can't understand the same things in the same ways.

Comment: This is a matter of taste. Sticking with standard texts is probably best. I found Kolmogorov & Fomin, "Introductory Real Analysis" good.

Comment: The "topology" section of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions has links to five places where this question has been answered already.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different viewpoints of topology and therefore many different books. If you're looking for something in general, I'd say that "The Topology of Fibre Bundles" by Norman Steenrod is a pretty good one. However, I prefer "Algebraic Topology" by Allen Hatcher. It's of course about algebraic topology more than topology in general but it's still my favourite.

Comment: I realize the question is vague, but since the asker is looking for a "good and easy book" about topology "that everyone can understand" I don't think the books you recommend are going to get them very far.

Comment: Of course, literal reading of that condition makes it un-meetable, so I think it is normal to simply skip nonsense conditions until the OP clarifies. :) @TylerBailey

Comment: The problem is just that topology is not an easy topic that everyone can understand. However, now you mention it, "Topology" by James Munkres is an 'easier' book I'd say.

Comment: that sounds fair enough! I agree Faetter, some people get the idea that toplogy is 50% rubber sheets and 50% fun when that simply is not the case ;)