# How can the set $\{1\}$ be in the co-finite topology?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I would like to clarify the definition of the co-finite topology. The general definition says this:

> Let $X$ be a non empty set. Then the collection of subsets of $X$ whose compliments are finite along with the empty set forms a topology on $X$, and is called the co-finite topology.

There is also the example of this statement:
$$
\tau = \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,3\}, X\}
$$
which is a co-finite topology because the compliments of all the subsets of X are finite.

Generally, I want to ask one question: why is the complement of each subset of $X$ finite? For example subset which contains only $\{1\}$ for example, complement of this subset is all number except $1$ right? then why is this finite?

Comment: Remember that complement is with respect to the full set $X$, which in the example seems to be $\{1,2,3\}$ (the cofinite topology is the discrete topology on a finite set).

Comment: Somewhere it ought to say that $X$ is a finite set; otherwise, most of those sets don't have a finite complement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check, that in order, that $\tau$ is the cofinite topology, the complement of $\{1\}$ has to be finite, so $X$ has to be finite.

On a finite set, the cofinite topology is simply $2^{X}$, the discrete topology, since any subset has a finite complement. So, if $\tau$ is a cofinite topology, then $X=\{1,2,3\}$. If $X$ is supposed to be some other set, then $\tau$ is not the cofinite topology.

Comment: if $X={1,2,3}$ then complement of $X$ is finite?

Comment: The complement of a set $A\subset X$ is $X\setminus A$. So the complement of $\{1\}$ is $\{2,3\}$, _if_ $X=\{1,2,3\}$. If $X$ is some infinite set, then $X\setminus\{1\}$ is cleary infinite, too, but then $\{1\}$ is _not_ cofinite. You did not tell us, what $X$ is supposed to be.

Comment: so it means that if set is finite,then complement of subsets of this set is also member of  original set

Comment: @dato complements are, as has already been mentioned, always inside some fixed set. In this case, everything is inside the fixed set $X$.

Comment: thanks in advance,i am new on topology,started today from this site   http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/general-topology/limit-point-of-a-set.html

Comment: @dato Given this question, you might want to take a bit of time to brush up on basic set theory before continuing with topology. It will be a big help along the way.

Comment: @dato: Then I assume, you got your question from [here](http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/general-topology/cofinite-topology.html), where it clearly says $X=\{1,2,3\}$. You should have either included this into the question or, better, the link. Also, this example for a cofinite topology is not the best one, since, as already mentioned, a finite $X$ is somewhat a degenerate case. Also, this site does not look like the best introduction for topology (no offense), maybe look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology) for some good introductions.

Comment: @dato I agree with Tomas that this does not seem like a good resource to learn from. It is filled with bad grammar and the page about the cofinite topology is not actually correct (it even contradicts itself).

Comment: could you give me some good  link which is easy for learn

Comment: Indeed! Reading the whole article made me shiver. Note, that _the_ cofinite topology contains _all_ cofinite sets, not only some. I provided a link in my last comment above this.

Comment: i found it and downloaded,thanks for link

Answer (score 2):

The claim is not that the complement of every subset of a set is finite. Rather, the collection of a subsets of a given set whose complement is finite forms a topology. This is not actually hard to check. If a bunch of subsets all have finite complement then certainly their union does so, too. Similarly, for finite intersections.

Comment: and do this subsets have  finite complements?or  complement of set itself is finite

Comment: @dato: it is important to notice that one can only talk about the complement of a **subset of another given set**, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29.

Answer (score 0):

In the above example, the set **{1}** is open which implies that **{1}'** is finite,this is only possible when **X** is finite.......and remember that the complement of a subset of a finite set is always finite,that is why in your example every subset of **X** is open.