# What are some interesting blogs about general topology?

Tags: general-topology, big-list, online-resources

We have several question asking about book recommendations for general topology - for example the posts linked to [Best book for topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology) or the posts mentioned in the relevant section  of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions. These posts range from beginner level books to a comprehensive reference.

Are there also some blogs that would be useful for somebody interested in general topology? I am interested in blogs intended for audience of any level, from beginners to research level.

Comment: This is not a blog purely dedicated to general topology, but we do have some interesting posts on the subject: https://etreseul.wordpress.com/

Comment: I think that general topology was demoted after some quagmire in the set theoretic topology front; now it's private topology. And since it's private, I am not at liberty to discuss these blogs. :-P

Answer (score 6):

- **[Dan Ma's Topology Blog](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/)**

  From the blog's [about page](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/about/):

  > This blog is not intended as a research blog. The focus is usually on fairly basic topological notions – normal spaces, compact spaces, [Lindelöf] property, metrizability, product spaces, and function spaces, just to name a few. I tend to write on topics or problems or examples that interest me. But there is a lot of contents in my blog that are geared toward readers taking courses in topology.

Comment: This answer is community wiki, with the hope that it becomes a **community** wiki answer. It is my express desire that instead of posting additional answers, users instead expand this answer in the basic format I have begun: name of blog with a link, followed by a _short_ description of the blog. This is an experiment of sorts to see how this use of CW works.