# Topology Book Recommendation

Tags: general-topology, book-recommendation

I am looking to take a graduate course in topology in a couple semesters, and I was wondering if there exists a book which gives a general overview of topology in the same way that Saunders Maclane's "Algebra 3rd ed" gives you a general overview of Algebra.

By this I mean covers the important topics, and has exercises that are not extremely difficult, but are more designed to increase your understanding of the concepts discussed.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best book for topology?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology)

Comment: I would say I gave more specific criteria rather than "best book to study from"

Comment: Yes, but the answers in that thread gave book names and explanations for their choices and I believe you have there the information you needed. Anyway, this is just my opinion

Answer (score 2):

[Topology by J. Munkres](http://www.amazon.ca/Topology-2nd-Edition-James-Munkres/dp/0131816292) is widely used out there. You can also have a look at [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology) for more recommendations.