# Suitability of topology book for self-study

Tags: general-topology

Good day,

I have an engineering background and I recently took an interest in topology. I found this book *Topology* (2015) by Marco Manetti (ISBN 978-3-319-16958-3) and starting going through it.

Unfortunately I am experiencing a lot of difficulties with his definitions in the introductory chapter, which correspondingly means I can't quite do the exercises contained therein. Although I do understand the set-theoretic notation he uses, I find it difficult to understand the significance of these definitions and to develop a kind of intuition for them. Hence the question: is this book suitable for a beginner in this subject?

Best wishes

Comment: Munkres' book is something of a standard for introductory topology. (Not that this comment is entirely relevant to your question!)

Comment: From just skimming the book, it does seem like it's written for beginners. The first chapter however is really written to motivate the subject and contains a hodgepodge of results. If you're having trouble with the first chapter, consider skipping to chapter 3, where a more standard introduction to general topology begins. If you still don't like the exposition in chapter 3, you can consider switching books (it's nice to have multiple books anyways). See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology) for some recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions both of you :)