# Recommendation for good papers/resources on Topology

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, soft-question, book-recommendation

So guys, I have just finished a short online layman course on Topology and quite well understand the rules, terms etc. used therein. Could you recommend me papers in topology that aren't very much advanced, but provide a joyful read, apt for my level (a typical BS level course)? And also texts/resources to move forward in my studies? The topics I now know well are:

1. Connected and Compact spaces
2. Metric and Normal spaces
3. Path lifting and Covering spaces
4. Quotients, gluing and simplicial complexes
5. Galois theory
6. Free groups and graphs; and
7. Group presentations

PS: Thanks for any help/recommendation in advance!

Comment: To me, Galois theory seems quite unrelated. For the rest, papers are probably not good, but standard textbooks -- did you search a bit? Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-of-topology-for-beginner

Comment: Start by finishing Engelking's *General Topology*. The compendium *Recent Progress in General Topology III* edited by Hart, van Mill and Simon is a good introduction to more advance topics in contemporary (2014) topology.

Comment: @PeterFranek Maybe he was talking Galois correspondence of covering spaces.