# Introductory book on Topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [choosing a topology text](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903/choosing-a-topology-text)
>   [Best book for topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology)

What book would you recommend for an undergraduate wanting to learn the basics of topology? I've come across several books that claim to give an introduction to the subject, but I wasn't sure which one(s) to pick.

Here are some of the books I came across:

- Introduction to Topology - Bert Mendelson
- Basic Topology - M.A. Armstrong
- First Concepts of Topology - William G. Chinn
- Topology Without Tears - Sidney A. Morris
- Topology - James Munkres

They don't go over the exact same topics, some are more in-depth than others, some seem to target slightly different audiences etc. What would be right for me (not necessarily from that list)? To give some more background, I want to learn topology because I feel it will be somewhat helpful in the field of Computer Vision.

Comment: This looks like a perfect candidate for a community wiki post.

Comment: @Alex: I wasn't sure because I specified that I was interested in topology because of Computer Vision. I suppose I could turn this into one once I get a few good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know point-set topology? If not, you should start with that; any good introductory analysis book will cover it. As far as general topology goes, Munkres is pretty much the standard nowadays, it would probably be the safest choice.

Answer (score 1):

Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis by George Simmons