# Fast paced book in point-set topology to move on to algebraic topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am sorry, if this is a repetition of previous questions. But my case is sightly different. I am a physics undergrad who wants to shift to pure maths, and I want to study topology. The supreme reference is apparently Munkres , but I think it would be too much of a time-investment to study point-set topology from it. I want a shorter treatment of point-set topology, so that I can quickly move on to algebraic topology. Two of the books which I am thinking about are Armstrong's 'Basic Topology' and Lee's 'Topological manifolds'. Do you think it could give a shorter more effective treatment. I am not completely new to topology, and have been exposed to it before in Physics. I understand the intuitive meaning of quotient spaces, compactness, topological groups, definition of fundamental group and homology.

Comment: Trying to rush your education in mathematics is a universally bad idea. Just read Munkres, and do it slowly and completely.

Comment: This seems - to some extent - related: [Topology needed for differential geometry](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159787/topology-needed-for-differential-geometry). (The OP studies physics, too.)

Comment: But the OP also mentions that he wants to study algebraic topology.

Comment: Munkres does not take as much as time as you think. Reading chapter 2,3,4,5 should be enough to move on.

Comment: @Sanchez: That is good advice. Thanks. I will think about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My case was similar to yours: I graduated in theoretical physics but then made the transition to pure mathematics, so I had to quickly get a good grasp of required background material. The fastest path I know to the essential point-set/metric topology needed to start algebraic topology is the recent textbook:

- **Runde, V.** - *A Taste of Topology*.

It develops all elementary concepts and proves all standard theorems in just ~165p. in a course-like set of rigorous lectures with exercises. I think it is the best supplement of, or starting point before, **Bredon**'s "*Topology and Geometry*", as this last title is geared towards algebraic topology and develops general and differential topology in a very succinct manner (although very complete!). That couple of books would make a quick route to what you want. You can check out [other suitable book collections at my Amazon listmanias](http://www.amazon.com/gp/richpub/listmania/byauthor/A3JZQYJIEJ9QYK/ref=cm_pdp_lm_all).

Comment: Thanks. I had at Runde, and it seems interesting and also concise.

Answer (score 7):

I think the perfect book for you would be Glen E. Bredon's "Topology and Geometry". It has a clear introduction to smooth manifolds as well. I use this book a lot and highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look. Bredons book looks too advanced to me, lacking examples and problems for a first read of topology

Comment: I will take this opportunity to advertise my own book "Topology and Groupoids" since it marries the geometric and categorical viewpoints, has lots of exercises and pictures; it covers some aspects, e.g. the use of groupoids for covering spaces and orbit spaces, not dealt with elsewhere. The e-version is available via kagi at £5. This new edition is published privately to cut the cost. Available from amazon.

Comment: Re "Topology and Groupoids": the pdf is now freely available on my web page www.groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html .