# Book on “topology ” for starters

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

This semester I have a course on topology. I'd like you to recommend me some books.

Comment: Topology without tears(?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Introductory book on Topology](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94242/introductory-book-on-topology) or [Choosing a text for a First Course in Topology](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903/choosing-a-text-for-a-first-course-in-topology)

Answer (score 1):

If "topology" means "general topology", I strongly recommend *General Topology* by Ryszard Engelking. It is the deepest monograph in this area I have ever met. It starts from zero and leads to the problems of contemporary topology (up to year of origin of the book).

Answer (score 0):

Munkres is the best to start in my opinion. Afterwards you can move on to Hatcher.